# How to open a pdf file given a url in android using third party application?

Tags: android, pdf

I have a number of urls that points to pdf files.  I would like to view these in my application using the third party application.  I have "Drive PDF Viewer".  I am using the code below.  When I press on a button on my app, that has a setOnCLickListener, the pdf file is downloaded, and instead of allowing me to choose the third party application that i would like to use to open my downloaded pdf, a web page is presented (yahoo website).  However, if i go to my notification drawer and click on the downloaded file, only then does the option to select "Drive PDF Viewer" is presented.  My question is, how do i go straight to choosing which third party pdf viewer i would like to use without having this webpage presented or having to access the notification drawer? I have no idea where this webpage comes from.

```
 pdfButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*Display pdf here*/
            Log.e("ArticleFragment", "pdf Button Pressed! url: " + pdfUrl);

            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdfUrl));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download the remote file yourself, storing it in a local cache directory, then use the same code but with the local URI.